# How to determine malloc heap statistics in a PIC32

Tags: c, memory-management, embedded, pic

I'm using malloc()/free() and friends on a pic32 processor, so no virtual memory and all that, just a fixed size heap that I declare at link time. Is there any way to determine at runtime, how much I've currently malloc'd? How much is available still? I've seen some references to a mallinfo() function, but the current pic32 libraries don't seem to support that.

Comment: why not just keep track of malloc/free ?

Comment: Do you have socket/tcp/ip available on the board?  If yes, then you could compile and link in a C library that sends info about memory usage out to the cloud and have it show up in a web browser.

Answer (score 3):

I've used both PIC18 and PIC24 processors and have found that the heap is to be used with caution. One trick is on device bootup, to determine heap size by using `malloc()`/`free()` with increasingly larger memory blocks until you find the limit. You can then track allocated memory on your own.

Caveats:

- All bets are off if you allocate/deallocate odd or large chunks of memory, as `malloc()` will fail if you happen to have enough free bytes of memory, but not in a contiguous block.
- If you use third party code that uses `malloc()`/`free()` you'll have to review/modify their code as well.

I've found that anything which can be done on the heap can be done with static memory or the stack, at the cost of refactoring code. Is that a viable option for you?

Have a look as this [related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/use-of-malloc-in-pic) at [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I am not sure if it's fair to compare PIC32 (MIPS based) to PIC18, those architectures are quite different. Keep in mind that PIC32 supports C++, networking and graphics stacks, where you may do stuff as complex as running a webserver for UI, limiting yourself to stack only for very large projects is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The below is a memory profiler written for the Arduino. It is taken from a post in the [Arduino forums](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,27536.msg204023.html#msg204023). You will need to make the necessary modifications to get it to work properly for a PIC. But it should be able to help you determine memory usage at runtime.

```
/*
 * Cut-and-pasted from www.arduino.cc playground section for determining heap and stack pointer locations.
 * http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory
 *
 * Also taken from the Pololu thread from Paul at: http://forum.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=989&view=unread#p4218
 *
 * Reference figure of AVR memory areas .data, .bss, heap (all growing upwards), then stack growing downward:
 * http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html
 *
 */

extern unsigned int __data_start;
extern unsigned int __data_end;
extern unsigned int __bss_start;
extern unsigned int __bss_end;
extern unsigned int __heap_start;
//extern void *__malloc_heap_start; --> apparently already declared as char*
//extern void *__malloc_margin; --> apparently already declared as a size_t
extern void *__brkval;
// RAMEND and SP seem to be available without declaration here

int16_t ramSize=0;   // total amount of ram available for partitioning
int16_t dataSize=0;  // partition size for .data section
int16_t bssSize=0;   // partition size for .bss section
int16_t heapSize=0;  // partition size for current snapshot of the heap section
int16_t stackSize=0; // partition size for current snapshot of the stack section
int16_t freeMem1=0;  // available ram calculation #1
int16_t freeMem2=0;  // available ram calculation #2


/* This function places the current value of the heap and stack pointers in the
 * variables. You can call it from any place in your code and save the data for
 * outputting or displaying later. This allows you to check at different parts of
 * your program flow.
 * The stack pointer starts at the top of RAM and grows downwards. The heap pointer
 * starts just above the static variables etc. and grows upwards. SP should always
 * be larger than HP or you'll be in big trouble! The smaller the gap, the more
 * careful you need to be. Julian Gall 6-Feb-2009.
 */
uint8_t *heapptr, *stackptr;
uint16_t diff=0;
void check_mem() {
  stackptr = (uint8_t *)malloc(4);          // use stackptr temporarily
  heapptr = stackptr;                     // save value of heap pointer
  free(stackptr);      // free up the memory again (sets stackptr to 0)
  stackptr =  (uint8_t *)(SP);           // save value of stack pointer
}


/* Stack and heap memory collision detector from: http://forum.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=989&view=unread#p4218
 * (found this link and good discussion from: http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1213583720%3Bstart=all )
 * The idea is that you need to subtract your current stack pointer (conveniently given by the address of a local variable)
 * from a pointer to the top of the static variable memory (__bss_end). If malloc() is being used, the top of the heap
 * (__brkval) needs to be used instead. In a simple test, this function seemed to do the job, showing memory gradually
 * being used up until, with around 29 bytes free, the program started behaving erratically.
 */
//extern int __bss_end;
//extern void *__brkval;

int get_free_memory()
{
  int free_memory;

  if((int)__brkval == 0)
     free_memory = ((int)&free_memory) - ((int)&__bss_end);
  else
    free_memory = ((int)&free_memory) - ((int)__brkval);

  return free_memory;
}


void setup()                    // run once, when the sketch starts
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop()                     // run over and over again
{
  Serial.print("\n\n--------------------------------------------");
  Serial.print("\n\nLOOP BEGIN: get_free_memory() reports [");
  Serial.print( get_free_memory() );
  Serial.print("] (bytes) which must be > 0 for no heap/stack collision");


  Serial.print("\n\nSP should always be larger than HP or you'll be in big trouble!");

  check_mem();

  Serial.print("\nheapptr=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) heapptr, HEX); Serial.print("] (growing upward, "); Serial.print( (int) heapptr, DEC); Serial.print(" decimal)");

  Serial.print("\nstackptr=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) stackptr, HEX); Serial.print("] (growing downward, "); Serial.print( (int) stackptr, DEC); Serial.print(" decimal)");

  Serial.print("\ndifference should be positive: diff=stackptr-heapptr, diff=[0x");
  diff=stackptr-heapptr;
  Serial.print( (int) diff, HEX); Serial.print("] (which is ["); Serial.print( (int) diff, DEC); Serial.print("] (bytes decimal)");


  Serial.print("\n\nLOOP END: get_free_memory() reports [");
  Serial.print( get_free_memory() );
  Serial.print("] (bytes) which must be > 0 for no heap/stack collision");


  // ---------------- Print memory profile -----------------
  Serial.print("\n\n__data_start=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) &__data_start, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) &__data_start, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  Serial.print("\n__data_end=[0x"); Serial.print((int) &__data_end, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) &__data_end, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  Serial.print("\n__bss_start=[0x"); Serial.print((int) & __bss_start, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) &__bss_start, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  Serial.print("\n__bss_end=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) &__bss_end, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) &__bss_end, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  Serial.print("\n__heap_start=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) &__heap_start, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) &__heap_start, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  Serial.print("\n__malloc_heap_start=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) __malloc_heap_start, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) __malloc_heap_start, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  Serial.print("\n__malloc_margin=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) &__malloc_margin, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) &__malloc_margin, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  Serial.print("\n__brkval=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) __brkval, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) __brkval, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  Serial.print("\nSP=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) SP, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) SP, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  Serial.print("\nRAMEND=[0x"); Serial.print( (int) RAMEND, HEX ); Serial.print("] which is ["); Serial.print( (int) RAMEND, DEC); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  // summaries:
  ramSize   = (int) RAMEND       - (int) &__data_start;
  dataSize  = (int) &__data_end  - (int) &__data_start;
  bssSize   = (int) &__bss_end   - (int) &__bss_start;
  heapSize  = (int) __brkval     - (int) &__heap_start;
  stackSize = (int) RAMEND       - (int) SP;
  freeMem1  = (int) SP           - (int) __brkval;
  freeMem2  = ramSize - stackSize - heapSize - bssSize - dataSize;
  Serial.print("\n--- section size summaries ---");
  Serial.print("\nram   size=["); Serial.print( ramSize, DEC ); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");
  Serial.print("\n.data size=["); Serial.print( dataSize, DEC ); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");
  Serial.print("\n.bss  size=["); Serial.print( bssSize, DEC ); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");
  Serial.print("\nheap  size=["); Serial.print( heapSize, DEC ); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");
  Serial.print("\nstack size=["); Serial.print( stackSize, DEC ); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");
  Serial.print("\nfree size1=["); Serial.print( freeMem1, DEC ); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");
  Serial.print("\nfree size2=["); Serial.print( freeMem2, DEC ); Serial.print("] bytes decimal");

  delay(3000);
}
```

Not an exact solution, but it should serve as a good starting point.

Comment: I was really excited by this. Unfortunately, the pic32 standard lib doesn't appear to define any of the __bss/__brk variables.

Comment: @TravisGriggs The [PIC Memory Map](http://www.microcontrollerboard.com/pic_memory_organization.html) doesn't match up too well with the [AVR Memory Map](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html). ***Read the comments, not the code.*** You can easily create the pointers you need once you understand the PIC memory map. Also, take a look at [this article](http://blog.flyingpic24.com/2008/02/28/the-stack-so-misunderstood/) about the PIC stack. It might help.